# how can i send bid messages to all neighbors in wireless range in ONE simulator?

Tags: nearest-neighbor, neighbours, dtn

I am trying to develop a routing protocol and i need send some bid messages to all nodes which are in my wireless range in ONE simulator and they should reply to this message, and according to information  in their reply messages i will choose one of those nodes for my next hope. how can send bid messages to all of nodes which are in my neighborhood?

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot what you mean by "bid messages" and when exactly you want to send them. You can get all currently connected hosts with the getConnections method in the routing module and you could for example iterate over that list when you want to make the bid and exchange this information (similar to what MaxProp does in changedConnection).

Comment: may i have your skype or whatsapp ID please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have resources for 1-1 support questions. Trying to use this forum instead to help a wider audience while at it.